# How to add fields in a module?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am currently using SugarCRM Version 6.5.16 (Build 1082) Community Edition.
I need to add a field called redeem points under the Sales Module.
After exploring studio, I cannot find any modules under the name of Sales. However I will need the field to be under the Sales Module instead of a new Module? 
May I know how do i go about doing it? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the Sales group tab? Within that tab you should see Leads, Opportunities, Accounts, etc as modules. Check for those names in Studio to edit the respective module.

Comment: yes i am referring to the sales group tab. I would want to create a module under the sales group tab. Am i suppose to just add a new field or add a new module? Thanks

Comment: You create a new module in Module Builder, deploy it (then working in Studio from there on out for any edits), and then under Admin->Configure Tabs you would add that module to the Sales tab. NOTE: Once you have deployed your module from Module Builder stop using it and use Studio only for ongoing edits.

Comment: i tried creating a new module but i got a pop up window saying "page at localhost says: an error has occured during deploying process, your package may not have installed correctly". May I know why is this so?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using a hosting provider. Their permissions are set up incorrectly for SugarCRM so it can't write the files during the deployment process. Send them the required file permissions. The Linux version is here: http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/02KB/02Administration/100Install/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux